# "Options ExecCGI is off in this directory" When try to run Ruby code using mod_ruby

Tags: configuration, installation, apache-2.2, ruby

I am on Ubuntu,
Apache 2.2
Installed the fcgi via apt-get then removed it via apt-get remove.
Installed mod-ruby
configuration I added to Apache:

```
  LoadModule ruby_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ruby.so
  RubyRequire apache/ruby-run
  <Directory /var/www>
    Options +ExecCGI
  </Directory>

  <Files *.rb>
    SetHandler ruby-object
    RubyHandler Apache::RubyRun.instance
  </Files>
  <Files *.rbx>
    SetHandler ruby-object
    RubyHandler Apache::RubyRun.instance
  </Files>
```

I have a file in the `www` direcoty with `puts 'baba'`
I have other files in that directory, all accessible via Apache.
Test file has been `chmod 777`
In the browser I get `403`.
In Apache error log I get:

```
[error] access to /var/www/t.rb failed for (null), reason: Options ExecCGI is off in this directory
```

If I move this to a sub folder `rubytest` and modify the relevant config to be:

```
<Directory /var/www/rubytest>
        Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

and making sure the directory has 755 permissions on it, it just try to download the file, as if it does not recognize the postfix *.rb any more

If I give directory and files 777 it fails:

> usr/lib/ruby/1.8/apache/ruby-run.rb:53:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir
>   /var/www/rubytest in LOAD_PATH, mode
>   040777 [Tue May 24 19:39:58 2011]
>   [error] mod_ruby: error in ruby [Tue
>   May 24 19:39:58 2011] [error]
>   mod_ruby:
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/apache/ruby-run.rb:53:in
>   `load': loading from unsafe file
>   /var/www/rubytest/t.rb (SecurityError)
>   [Tue May 24 19:39:58 2011] [error]
>   mod_ruby:   from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/apache/ruby-run.rb:53:in`
>   handler'

**BUT, IF I USE *.rbx it works like a charm...go figure.**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have an `.htaccess` file in `/var/www` with its own `Options` - it may be overriding your `Directory` block.

Also, `/var/www` is likely your document root and may be inheriting some other default options with higher precedence. Try moving your script to a new directory called, for example, `/var/www/ruby`; and modifying your `Directory` block accordingly.

Comment: I updated my question, now it looks even badder :-)